# Date is encoded. Can't figure it out.

Tags: cryptography

I have dates that are encoded in a MSSQL db but we need to crack the date encoding to build some software that can plug-in to the db(which belongs to us).

01/20/2011 = 76724

03/08/2011 = 76771

10/11/2011 = 76988

11/10/2011 = 77018

Any ideas on the encoding being used?

Comment: improperly tagged?

Comment: Looks to me like it's just the number of days since $76724$ days before 1/20/2011. Microsoft Excel can do the conversion pretty easily.

Comment: Why did you think these dates were encoded? Encoded data should look random, not regular as this does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be the number of days since 28 December 1800.

Calculations checked with http://www.timeanddate.com/date/dateadd.html.

Comment: This appears to be the native date format of [Clarion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarion_programming_language); see e.g. [here](http://www.clarionmag.com/cmag/v4/v4n12exceldates.html) or [here](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/jclarion/clarion-runtime/1.46/clarion-runtime-1.46-javadoc.jar!/org/jclarion/clarion/runtime/CDate.html).